# The 'CPPCheck Plugin Package' package did not load correctly

Tags: visual-studio-2013, cppcheck

Geting "The 'CPPCheck Plugin Package' package did not load correctly" after installing CppcheckPlugin.vsix on MVS 2013.

Anyone know how to fix this?[image]

Downloaded from https://github.com/VioletGiraffe/cppcheck-vs-addin/releases/tag/1.3.1.0

released this 18 days ago
written
Fixed an error with VS 2013
but still issue.
Thanks.

Comment: There's a bug report for that: https://github.com/VioletGiraffe/cppcheck-vs-addin/issues/142
It has supposedly been fixed, and now it works for some people and still doesn't work for others. If you're among the unlucky ones (and you have the latest version of the plugin), please leave a comment on that issue with your OS version, VS version and the log file that the error message mentions.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe currently I am unable to test that, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the `cppcheck` program to be able to usethe `cppcheck-vs-addin`. The plugin needs `cppcheck` to be installed, otherwise it will not work correctly and visual will report the error you see.

Furthermore cppcheck depends on microsoft packages but its installer doesnt provide it. For instance The latest cppcheck (1.72) depends on Visual 2015 packages (`msvcp140.dll`, `vcruntime140.dll`, etc...).

What you need to do :

- Download [visual 2015 redistributable packages](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145)
- Install cppcheck version 1.7x

Comment: How can a C# VS extension depend on C++ runtime? I don't think you're right. There was indeed a problem with .NET assembly dependencies, and it's not somewhat fixed, but C++ runtime was never a problem.